# How to read a section from web.config on IIS7 w/ .net 4 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iis-7, web-config

I've got the following section in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:00:30" />

        <remove fileExtension=".ogv" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />

        <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />

        <!-- and a bunch more... -->
    </staticContent>
    <!-- ... -->
</system.webServer>
```

Here's what I'm trying to do in psuedo-code:

```
var ext = ".ogg";
var staticContentElements = GetWebConfig().GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent").ChildElements;
var mimeMap = staticContentElements.Where(c =>
                   c.GetAttributeValue("fileExtension") != null && 
                   c.GetAttributeValue("fileExtension").ToString() == ext
               ).Single();

var mimeType = mimeMap.GetAttributeValue("mimeType").ToString();
```

**Basically, I need to search the mimeMaps by a fileExtension and get their mimeType.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George Stocker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098406/how-to-read-a-section-from-web-config-on-iis7-w-net-4-in-c#answer-5098434) led me to a Google search for`["staticContent" custom configuration section]` which brought me to an iis.net article titled [Adding Static Content MIME Mappings <mimeMap>](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap).

The article led me to come up with:

```
using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    var siteName = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
    var config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration(siteName);
    var staticContentSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");
    var staticContentCollection = staticContentSection.GetCollection();

    var mimeMap = staticContentCollection.Where(c =>
        c.GetAttributeValue("fileExtension") != null &&
        c.GetAttributeValue("fileExtension").ToString() == ext
    ).Single();

    var mimeType = mimeMap.GetAttributeValue("mimeType").ToString();
    contentType = mimeType.Split(';')[0];
}
```

Which works perfectly for me. I just need to add some `null` checks here and there and it should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [create a custom configuration section](http://www.yapb.net/post/2009/09/22/Creating-your-own-Custom-Configuration-Section.aspx) to get that information.